# Change color of missing values in Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Consider the example of missing values in the [Seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.randn(10, 200))
mask = np.zeros_like(corr)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, vmax=.3, square=True)
```

[image: Heatmap]

How do I change the color of the missing values to, for example, black? The color of the missing values should be specified independent of the color scheme of the heatmap, it may not be present in the color scheme.

I tried adding `facecolor = 'black'` but that didn't work. The color can be affected by e.g. `sns.axes_style("white")` but it isn't clear to me how that can be used to set an arbitrary color.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.randn(10, 200))
mask = np.zeros_like(corr)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
g = sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, vmax=.3, square=True)
g.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')
```

You need to use `set_facecolor` on the plot object. Change to any colour you want.

Resulting in this graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it strange that adding `facecolor = 'xkcd:salmon'` as a keyword argument doesn't work?

Comment: It is a little strange. facecolor is listed as a valid kwarg of Axes.pcolormesh. So presumably there is something that overrides it?

Comment: I guess Seaborn does that, probably the axes styling. It is frustrating that these things are not clearly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to set the active style parameters in seaborn using sns.set_style():

```
sns.set_style("white",  {'figure.facecolor': 'black'})
corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.randn(10, 200))
mask = np.zeros_like(corr)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, vmax=.3, square=True)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

An entire list of parameters can be found here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#overriding-elements-of-the-seaborn-styles